# Does $((x-1)! \bmod x) - (x-1) \equiv 0\implies \text{isPrime}(x)$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Does $$((x-1)! \bmod x) - (x-1) = 0$$

imply that $x$ is prime?

Comment: Yes with the exception of $x=1$, which is neither prime nor composite, but satisfies the identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is known as [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

It's not very practical as a primality test, because the amount of calculation it requires is more than even the obvious tests.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that this is the *easy* direction of Wilson's theorem.  I have often seen Wilson's Theorem stated without the "if and only if" because this second direction is so easy to prove:

**Proof:** If $x > 1, x \ne 4$ were not prime, then the product $(x-1)!$ would contain two factors multiplying to get $x$, and thus we would have $(x - 1)! \equiv 0 \pmod x$, contradicting the statement.  On the other hand if $x = 4$, then $(x - 1)! = 6 \equiv 2 \not \equiv -1$ so in any case $x$ must be prime.

At one point $4$ was my favorite integer for precisely the reason that it was the only exception to $(x - 1)! \equiv 0 \text{ or } 1 \pmod x$.